# AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use google drive.api I ran

```java
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\orion\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\teachervoiceorganization\\JavaProject\\client_id.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
            new InputStreamReader(in));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("515427348790")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("i50nkSMoqVegC0UdkD1W8g3Y")) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=drive "
                        + "into drive-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
            Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE)).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
            .build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
```

I get the issue with

```java
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Where is the user id located? I have looked on the https://console.developers.google.com and there is no luck. anything will help.

Comment: Your question is unclear what user id are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The Google user ID is encoded as the `sub` of the JWT returned from the call to exchange the Auth Code for tokens. You're using the Java client library which obfuscates everything, so where the JWT token is exposed is anybody's guess. My personal advice is discard the library and just call the two OAuth URLs directly. 
The steps are:-

1. Construct the OAuth request URL containing your client ID, scopes and callback URL
2. Redirect to that URL
3. When the browser redirects back to your callback Servlet, call the token endpoint to request the tokens including the identity.

This is all described really well at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Nb, you need to include the `email` scope as well as the appropriate Drive scope(s).